# python method override with multiple inheritance and instancing

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Here is my code -  my base_file.py

```
class modify_file(object):
    def modify_file_delete_obj():
        print "modify file here"

    def modify_file_add_attributes():
        print "modify file here"
        return ["data"]

class task_list(object):
    modify_file_instance = modify_file() #problem part when accessing from project1.py
    def check_topology():
        data = modify_file_instance.modify_file_add_attributes()
        #use this data further in this method


    def check_particles():
        print "check for particles"
```

project1.py file

```
import base_file as base_file
class project1(base_file.modify_file,base_file.task_list):
    #overriding method of modify_file class
    def modify_file_add_attributes(self):
        print "different attributes to modify"
        return ["different data"]
```

The idea is to run base_file.py for most projects and the project specific ones when required.
But when i run the method

```
"check_topology" from project1.py
```

the modify_file class is being derived from the base_file.py not project1.py

```
So the output is still ["data"] not ["different data"]
```

Comment: Semantically a cat is a pet but a pet is not always a cat. So the inheritance is kind of upside down. Meaning `cat` should subclass `pet` (which could subclass `animal`).

Comment: agree.. my actual code was in a different context ...

Comment: I guess you should inherit the `dog` and `cat` class from a `pet` class.

Comment: @user2015144 No problem, but a misleading example is hard to reason about - which makes proposing adequate solutions hard/impossible.

Comment: In my actual code the cat class was actually having some ui code multi-threaded and dog class having a  socket listening but had some simpler methods which i wanted to override from a separate file (for the pet class that is inheriting dog and cat)

Comment: @user2015144. Please edit your question and provide a more coherent example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to correctly use inheritance, define a base class `Pet` which provides a method to be overridden by a specific kind of pet.

```
class Pet(object):
    def talk(self):
        pass

class Cat(Pet):
    def talk(self):
        return "meow"

class Dog(Pet):
    def talk(self):
        return "woof"

pets = [Cat(), Dog(), Cat()]
for p in pets:
    print(p.talk())

# Outputs
#   meow
#   woof
#   meow
```

(I leave the issue of what `Pet.talk` should do, if anything, as a topic for another question.)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) with [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

The `task_list` class uses object composition when it creates an internal instance of the `modify_file` class. But there is a problem here in that you are creating it as a *class attribute*, which means it will be shared by all instances of `task_list`. It should instead be an *instance attribute* that is created in an `__init__` method:

```
class task_list(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(task_list, self).__init__()
        self.modify_file_instance = modify_file()

    def check_topology(self):
        data = self.modify_file_instance.modify_file_add_attributes()
```

The `project1` class uses multiple inheritance, when in fact it should use single inheritance. It is a kind of `task_list`, so it makes no sense for it to inherit `modify_file` *as well*. Instead, it should create it's own internal sub-class of `modify_file` - i.e. use object composition, just like `task_list` class does:

```
# custom modify_file sub-class to override methods
class project1_modify_file(base_file.modify_file):
    def modify_file_add_attributes(self):
        print "different attributes to modify"
        return ["different data"]

class project1(base_file.task_list):
    def __init__(self):
        super(project1, self).__init__()
        self.modify_file_instance = project1_modify_file()
```

Now you have a consistent interface. So when `project1.check_topology()` is called, it will in turn call `task_list.check_topology()` (by inheritance), which then accessses `self.modify_file_instance` (by composition):

```
>>> p = project1()
>>> p.check_topology()
different attributes to modify
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `dog` class you're re-constructing an instance of `cat`, this instance (and the `cat` type) does not know they are inherited elsewhere by `pets`.

So you can naturally try:

```
class cat(object):
    def meow(self):
        self.sound = "meow"
        return self.sound

class dog(object):
    def woof(self):
        return self.meow()


class pets(cat,dog):
    def meow(self):
        self.sound = "meow meow"
        return self.sound

print(pets().woof())
```

Which still make no sense with those actual names, but you told they are fake names so it make be OK.

Comment: The idea was to call dog in an instance and pets in a different instance